# How to get info on a dead process that was listening on a particular port?

Tags: process, crash, forensics

There is a process that I know was listening on a certain port that is no longer running.

I would like to know when it stopped running, if it crashed, or any other info about that process.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Unless there are log leavings or maybe a core file, it's gone.

Comment: To my knowledge you won't be able to determine anything if logging was not enabled either system wide (i.e. `auditd`) or specifically for that process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is not much that you can investigate if the process haven't logged anything implicitly or some kind of system wide logging solution was not deployed (most probably `auditd`).

Assuming you don't know what that process was trying to accomplish what you can do is:

- Run `last` and `last -f /var/log/btmp | less` or `faillog` to look for suspicious successful or failed login attempts.
- Check `/var/log/secure` for any authentication related clues
- Check `/var/cron/tab` and `/etc/crontab` to find any newly added jobs if any (also checking `/var/log/cron` would help to identify some suspicious jobs that were run which means that the `cron` configuration was modified to look in other folders for extra jobs)
- Run `lsmod` for any suspicious kernel modules that are currently loaded (also `dkms status` for dynamically loaded ones)

You also can check all the log files either by hand or grepping for a process name (if you know it). And yes, check `/var/log/audit` just in case `auditd` is set up and running. If so, you would probably find out some more information.

Anyway, it's more about searching for a needle in a haystack. You should make a lot of educated (or not so educated) guesses about what that process was doing to find anything.

Answer (score 4):

That depends almost entirely on the logging options of the program related with said process.

"Almost" because crashes for causes external to the process should be logged by the system (out of disk space, out of memory etc.)